# Link to a Controller function with parameter from a View (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, codeigniter

Using CodeIgniter I am trying to create a link that the user can click within a view to show them the details of a record in my database.

In ASP.NET MVC3 with C# I would do it with `@Html.ActionLink("Controller", "Action", new { id = item.Id})`

This is my session controllers index() function

```
public function index()
{
        $data['sessions'] = $this->session_model->get_sessions();

        $this->load->view('_header');
        $this->load->view('session/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('_footer');
}
```

This is the index view it loads where I want to be able to click the link to go to enter() function

```
<table>

<th>Session Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Host</th>
<th></th>

<?php foreach ($sessions as $session_item): ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $session_item['sessionName'] ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $session_item['sessionDesc'] ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $session_item['adminName'] ?> </td>
        <td> <a id="enterSession" href=<?php echo site_url("session/enter" + $session_item['id']) ?> >Enter</a></td>

    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

The enter session points me to the url "http://192.168.1.36/index.php/1" (if the id of my item is 1) whereas I expect "http://192.168.1.36/index.php/session/enter/1"

Any ideas on how I can make it call the enter() function also in the session controller (shown below)

```
 public function enter($id) {

        $this->load->view('_header');
        $this->load->view('session/enter');
        $this->load->view('_footer');
    }
```

Comment: To get the url to point to the correct place- in the href, try adding a trailing slash to `"session/enter"`. Or pass an array like- `$segments = array('session', 'enter', $session_item['id']);` to `site_url()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in the string concatenation in your PHP code.  Perhaps it will work to use:

```
site_url("session/enter" . $session_item['id'])
```

... rather than a `+` sign between the two strings.

Regarding the second question - it looks correct as-is.  Is it failing to call the `session` controller's `enter()` function passing the `$id` as an argument (assuming the URL is correct)?.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I did indeed need to change the `+` to a `.` Oh and add a / character. So this now works :)

`<td> <a id="enterSession" href=<?php echo site_url("session/enter/" . $session_item['id']) ?> >Enter</a></td>`